# Does string concatenation turn out to be compile-time constant?

Tags: java

I study from OCP O'Reilly book for Java.

There is a statement such that:

> `15: String first = "rat" + 1;`
>
> On line 15, we have a compile-time constant that automatically gets
> placed in the string pool as "rat1"

I cannot understand why concatenation operation generates compile-time constant. In my understanding, the operation should be done at run-time. What is the point I am missing?

Comment: The compiler sees the code, convert it to make more sense, and then run it.

Comment: *"the operation should be done at run-time"* - why? Why do you think that is or should be? It is not like you can get different results if you run this code a million times, it will **always** be `"rat1"` so why not evaluate it during compile time?

Comment: At compile time, Strings are resolved to eliminate the concatenation operator(+) if possible.

Comment: It's no different to seeing `int n = 1 + 1` and compiling that into `int n = 2`.  Compilers have been doing that since the dawn of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Strings are created with the help of **String literals** and **+** operator, they get concatenated at **compile time**. This is referred to as Compile-Time Resolution of Strings.

When Strings are created with the help of **String literals** along with **variables** and **+** operator, they get concatenated at **runtime** only, as the value of the variables cannot be predicted beforehand. This is referred to as the RunTime Resolution of Strings.

Consider the below example

```
// Strings are computed in compile-time in this case.
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String first = "rat1";
   String result = "rat" + 1;

   System.out.println(first == result); //prints true
}
```

However, in the code below, the Strings are computed in runtime because the variable **one** is not a constant expression:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String first = "rat1";
   String one = "1";
   String result = "rat" + one;

   System.out.println(first == result); //prints false
}
```

You can also refer to this link which has a more detailed explanation. [CompileTime Vs RunTime Resolution of Strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compiletime-vs-runtime-resolution-of-strings/)